# Brushless motor runs for 10 seconds and shuts down

Tags: brushless-motors

I armed the ESC and set the throttle and the motor spins up for about 10 seconds. However, it is slow and then shuts down. After turning the throttle back down and then back up the motor starts again. It uses 40V so this motor should be running at a faster speed.

Comment: Sounds like a low voltage problem. Using a smoke stopper by chance ? Is the motor or ESC heating up ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that your battery can't cope with the load from the motor. As a result its voltage sags until the ESC's low-voltage-cutoff turns it off.

You can tell if this is the case by monitoring the battery voltage as you run the motor.